# Database Table Path Combinations

Tags: mysql, database, path, filenames

I am designing a database that is going to store all the instruction videos / text / audio paths for using a device. The user can select whether they want the instructions to come in the form of video, text, or audio (can pick any of the 3, but has to pick at least 1). The user will also pick a language, this will be the language that the instructions come in. I think I have a few of the table structures figured out. However, how do I want to store all the combinations into one table?

For example, one of my tables has all the file path combinations,

```
path_id      button_text       audio_path       video_path        text_path
1            cbl.txt           null             null              cbl.txt
2            cbl.txt           null             cbl.mp4           null
3            cbl.txt           null             cbl.mp4           cbl.txt
4            cbl.txt           cbl.mp3          null              null
5            cbl.txt           cbl.mp3          null              cbl.txt
6            cbl.txt           cbl.mp3          cbl.mp4           null
7            cbl.txt           cbl.mp3          cbl.mp4           cbl.txt
8            bolt.txt          null             null              bolt.txt
9            bolt.txt          null             bolt.mp4          null
10           bolt.txt          null             bolt.mp4          bolt.txt
11           bolt.txt          bolt.mp3         null              null
12           bolt.txt          bolt.mp3         null              bolt.txt
13           bolt.txt          bolt.mp3         bolt.mp4          null
14           bolt.txt          bolt.mp3         bolt.mp4          bolt.txt
```

This takes into account all the different combinations, so based on the settings that the user picks, they will be returned the primary key corresponding to the right settings. However, I think this is too redundant and may not be very efficient, what is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

device table:

```
  device_id   device_name
     1          machine1
```

files table

```
  file_id   device_id  file_type  file_path
     1        1           video     d:\videos\v1.mp4
     2        1            text     d:\texts\t1.txt
     3        1            pdf      d:\pdfs\p1.pdf
      ...
```

Or if one file can be used for multiple devices, add another table:

device_file table:

```
   device_id  file_id
      1          1
      1          2
      2          2

     ...
```

and you can remove the "device_id" column in your files table.

Comment: I think this approach works, but won't the file_path become redundant once a new device is added? What if you kept the device table the same, omitted device_id from the files table and made a linking table that paired the primary keys?

Comment: if one file can be used for multiple devices, you need another table to store the relationship between devices and files